# Correctness of algorithm to find maximum in array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, max, correctness

I want to show correctness of "Algorithm to find maximum element in array" using induction and contradiction.

```
ans=-infinity
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    ans= max(ans, A[i])
```

where `A[0:n-1]` is array and `max` is the function to return maximum of its two arguments.

What I am doing:

Base case: `i=0, ans= max(-infinity,A[0])=A[0]`, as only one element has been processsed, it is maximum.

Induction Hypothesis: `i=k<n-1,` assume the algorithm correctly find maximum upto k iterations.

Inductive Step: `i=k+1`, let `ans_{i}` denote maximum element obtained by algorithm upto `i` steps and let `ans'_{i}` denote another maximum element from array `A[0:i-1]`.

Then from induction hypothsis, `ans_{k} = ans'_{k}`

Now, for the sake of contradiction, assume `ans_{k+1} < ans'_{k+1}`

Now, how should I proceed to show this contradiction ?

Any suggestion? Should I change this approach ?

Comment: Belonging to math.stackexchange.com (which the "belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network " does not offer as suggestion. Seriously SO guys, is it so hard to put an "Other" option in the list of suggestions?)

Comment: You don't need the proof from contradiction, as the induction proof does the job already.

Comment: What a mumbo-jumbo of notations there, beat me if I understood what you trying to achieve. Look, the problem can be simply put as: "If M(i-1) is the max for `arr[0...i-1]`, then M(i)=max(`arr[i]`, M(i-1)) is the max for `arr[0...i]`". And the demo is simple: "if M(i-1)>=`arr[i]`, then M(i-1)=M(i) - by max function definition - will be bigger than any `arr[0...i]`. If M(I-1)<`arr[i]` then `arr[i]` is bigger than any `arr[0...i-1]` - by the transitivity of the order operation - so M(i)=arr[i] - exactly the same value as return by the max function"

Answer (score 0):

Where n is zero, we obtain -infinity. Where n is one or higher, we obtain max2( ans_(n-1), A[n-1]). So induction works, unless max2(-infinity, x) returns 
-infinity, which it might if A[n-1] = NaN. The contradiction step actually shows that the function maybe isn't a rigorous as it should be.